# .find is not a function error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm developing a node js rest server and having an issue with my Schema queries. When I hit my end points I get the error `TypeError: user.find is not a function`

The following is my user.js file

```
var {mongoose} = require('../../dbcore/mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

module.exports = mongoose.model('User',new Schema( {

    basicId: Schema.ObjectId,

    activePurchaseIDs: {
        type: [Schema.ObjectId],
        default: []
    },

    activeOrderIDs: {
        type: [Schema.ObjectId],
        default: []
    },

    paymentOptionIDs: {
        type: [Schema.ObjectId],
        default: []
    },

    addressIDs: {
        type: [Schema.ObjectId],
        default: []
    },

    interestIDs: {
        type: [Schema.ObjectId],
        default: []
    }

}));
```

and this is where it's imported/required.

```
var URLS = require('./urls');
var User = require('../schemas/user/user');

function init(app,mongoose) {

    app.get(URLS.USERS_URL,(req,res)=>{

        var user = new User({});

        user.find().then((users)=>{
            res.send({users});
        },(err)=>{
            res.status(400).send(err);
        });


    });



}

module.exports = init;
```

I was following a tutorial while writing this code and I was expecting it to work as I followed the tutorial step by step.

Comment: Can you add a link to the tutorial?

Comment: @Barmar I can't because it's on udemy.

Comment: Have you connected to the db with `mongoose.connect(url)`?

Comment: Yes : ```var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017');

module.exports = {mongoose};``` @DavidKamer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `var user = new User({})` you are creating a new MongoDB document based on the `User` model and assigning it to `var user`.

A single `user` document does not have a `find()` function, but your `User` model does.

```
var user = new User({});
User.find().then(...);
```

Comment: Can you call `.find()` without an empty object? I get confused on this because you have to in Mondo shell.

Comment: In mongo shell, calling `db.collection.find()` with no arguments will return all documents in the collection

Answer (score 1):

```
app.get(URLS.USERS_URL, async (req,res)=>{

    const userList = await User.find();

    if(!userList) {
      res.status(500).json({success: false});
    }
    res.send(userList);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your call to the database needs to look like this:

```
User.find().then((users)=>{
    res.send({users});
     }).catch((err)=>{
       res.status(400).send(err);
      });
```

You should call it directly on the module, because mongoose will handle creation implicitly and creating a new object isn't neccesary.

I'm not sure if your schema is correctly defined, but I'm not going to say your tutorial is wrong on that. You should go into mongo shell and check if the schema was created to verify it was designed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wrote wrong this so check your file exports `module.exports = XYZ` format.

PS:- I wrote like this `exports.module = XYZ`